# Explanation for limits equality.

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {\left( {\frac{{{a^x} + {b^x}}}{2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{x}}} = \exp \left( {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\frac{{{a^x} + {b^x}}}{2} - 1}}{x}} \right)$$

I am familiar with the "taking the exponent trick" which bring us to:

$$\\exp \left( {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left( {\frac{{{a^x} + {b^x}}}{2}} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{x}} \right)
$$

I truly don't get it. I'll be glad for an explanation.
Cheers!

Clarification: $exp(A) = e^A$.

Comment: $\ln(1+t)\simeq t$, for small values of *t*. In your case, $1+t=\dfrac{a^x+b^x}2$, since both expressions tend to $1$ as their arguments (*t* and *x*) tend to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{\frac 1 x}=\exp\left(\frac 1 x{\color{\red}\ln}\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)\right).
\end{align*}

Now, as $x\to0$, $(a^x+b^x)/2\to (a^0+b^0)/2=(1+1)/2=1$ (assuming that $a,b\neq0$). Also, $\ln(1)=0=1-1$, so that $\lim_{y\to1}\ln y=\lim_{y\to1}(y-1)$, since both functions are continuous at 1. Let $y\equiv(a^x+b^x)/2$. As have seen, $y\to1$ as $x\to0$, so that we have
$$\lim_{x\to0}\ln\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)=\lim_{y\to1}\ln y=0=\lim_{y\to1}(y-1)=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}-1\right).$$

**Edit: My previous solution contained an error, as pointed out by @AndréNicolas. I apologize. This is a revised version.**

From here, we have that (pulling the limit inside is possible, since $x\mapsto\exp(x)$ is continuous)
\begin{align*}
=&\,\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{\frac 1 x}=\lim_{x\to0}\exp\left(\frac 1 x{\color{\red}\ln}\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x\ln\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)\right)\\
=&\,\exp\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac1 x\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}-1\right)\right),
\end{align*}
*provided* that the two limits in the parentheses in the last two expressions are equal. But this is not too difficult to show. We can use L'Hôpital's rule, since both $\ln((a^x+b^x)/2)$ and $(a^x+b^2)/2-1$ converge to $0$ as $x\to 0$, as shown above, and the denominator $x$ naturally converges to zero in a sufficiently smooth way in each case, so that L'Hôpital's rule is applicable. I leave it as an exercise to show that the limit is $(\ln a+\ln b)/2$ in both cases, provided that $a,b>0$. (Hint: Use the fact that $(a^x)'=a^x\cdot\ln a$ for any $a>0$.)

Comment: WOW. Thanks mate, I really appreciate your work.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You're right. For a moment, I though the limit was zero. It's wrong, of course. Thanks for pointing out. I'll try to rework it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** In limits of the form
$$\lim_{x\to a} {(f(x))^{g(x)}}$$
if it turns out that $\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to a} {g(x)}=\infty$, then the following transformation may works:

$$\begin{align*} \lim_{x\to a} {(f(x))^{g(x)}} &=\lim_{x\to a} {(1+(f(x)-1))^{g(x)}}\\ &=\lim_{x\to a} {\{(1+(f(x)-1))^{1/(f(x)-1)}\}^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}}\\ &= e^{\lim_{x\to a}{g(x)(f(x)-1)}}\end{align*}$$

Now in your example $f(x)=\frac{{{a^x} + {b^x}}}{2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, so...

---

I hope it helps.

Comment: It is surely helps. Thank you sir!

Comment: Your Welcome! Just an old trick! :)

Answer (score 1):

Going to 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)}{x}\tag{1}$$ then presents no problem for you.

For brevity, let $t=f(x)=\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}-1$. Note that when $x$ is near $0$, then $f(x)$ is near $0$. Rewrite $\ln(1+f(x))$ (when $f(x)\ne 0$) as
$$f(x) \frac{\ln(1+f(x))}{f(x)}.$$
So to find (1) we need to find 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\cdot \frac{\ln(1+f(x))}{f(x)}.$$
The limit as $t\to 0$ of $\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}$ is $1$, which gives the desired result.

**Remark:** We are basically expanding $\ln(1+f(x))$ in a power series (first two terms only).

Comment: Yes, thank you. When I first wrote it out, $f(x)$ was intended to be $\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}$. But calling that $1+f(x)$ seemed neater, and I did not make all the changes.

Comment: Maple and WA are giving me $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ for an answer to this problem.  I've been trying to figure that out, but I don't see where that solution is coming from.  Any ideas?

Comment: Comes out routinely from  L'Hospital's Rule. If you have any trouble I can write the solution.  One could also have used L'H. directly, without the calculations of the question as posed.

Comment: Ah.  Brain malfunction. Thank you.